# Check if currrent value is bigger than the previous

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, gatsby

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
        "Mode": [
          {
            "level": 4,
            "moduleDetails": "some text"
          },
          {
            "level": 5,
            "modeDetails": "some teext 2"
          },
          {
            "level": 6,
            "modeDetails": "some text 3"
          },
          {
            "level": 4,
            "modeDetails": "some text 4"
          }
        ]
```

I need to loop through this array and check if the current value of key "level" is bigger than the previous one in the loop, and if it is I need to return true. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking for. Consider improving your question.

Comment: maybe better now :)

Comment: And what's the problem? Loop over the elements and compare the levels of the current element (`i`) and the one before that (`i - 1`)

Comment: Please add what you have tried and your challenge with that attempt.

Comment: Hi Andreas, yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it in your case

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    "level": 4,
    "moduleDetails": "some text"
  },
  {
    "level": 5,
    "modeDetails": "some teext 2"
  },
  {
    "level": 6,
    "modeDetails": "some text 3"
  },
]

const arr2 = [
  {
    "level": 4,
    "moduleDetails": "some text"
  },
  {
    "level": 5,
    "modeDetails": "some teext 2"
  },
  {
    "level": 3,
    "modeDetails": "some text 3"
  },
]

const check = (arr) => arr.every((item, i) => !arr[i - 1]?.level || arr[i - 1]?.level < item.level)

console.log(check(arr1))
console.log(check(arr2))
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Why `.every()`? Why it has to be a one-liner? What's with the optional chaining?

Answer (score -1):

#### You can loop the array using `forEach` and do the necessary check.

```js
const array = [
  { level: 4, moduleDetails: "some text" },
  { level: 5, modeDetails: "some teext 2" },
  { level: 6, modeDetails: "some text 3" },
  { level: 4, modeDetails: "some text 4" },
];

array.forEach((o, i) => i != 0 && console.log(o.level > array[i - 1].level));
```